# Creating dir structures for multiple users as the superuser Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

So I created my users.... Now for each of there dir's I have to create the following structure.

Users Home Directory / Staff / Info / Personal

Then create a file in each dir called file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt

I tried something like mkdir  create "users home directory / staff / info / personal but had no success I also cant find any help from research online. Yes I am very new to Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script. Modify USER_LIST to suit your needs and delete the `echo` keywords when you've verified the script does what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER_LIST="user1 user2 user3 user4"

cd /home || exit 1;
for user in $USER_LIST; do
    echo mkdir -p "$user"/{Staff,Info,Personal};
    for dir in Staff Info Personal; do
        echo touch "$user"/$dir/file{1,2,3}.txt;
    done;
done;
```

On the other hand, you could have modified the `/etc/skel` template before creating the users.

Comment: +1 for /etc/skel alone. But what happens if a username contains a space (or can it)?

Comment: how could i modify the /etc/skel template?

Comment: @Xen2050 I've heard usernames can contain spaces in some niche cases (like if they are synced with a Windows Active Directory domain). So ideally `USER_LIST` should be changed to an array `users`.

Comment: @dsstorefile You should always use lowercase variable names in Bash. Uppercase variables are special, like shell variables (e.g. `RANDOM`) or environment variables (e.g. `USER`).